# Error on upload .war file in weblogic

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, jdeveloper

I have already deployed my web apps into a WAR file. The next process, i want to upload my web apps to weblogic but i get error message.

> An error occurred during activation of changes, please see the log for details.
>   Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class oracle.adf.share.ADFContext
>   Error Could not initialize class oracle.adf.share.ADFContext

in the war file, i have already include all library jar files.
what caused error above?

for notes:
i am using oracle jdeveloper IDE 12c and weblogic server 12c

Comment: Is the class `oracle.adf.share.ADFContext` in the jars? Do you put the jars under WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: yes it is, i have already put the jars file under WEB-INF/lib. i think, my weblogic doesn't have ADF runtime. Is it correct? should I use Oracle Enterprise Manager instead of weblogic?